# Reducing cell frame doesn't animate the same as enlarging the frame

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview

Using the following code, to change the cell's frame and then animate the change.

```
   if (_new_h == 200){
        _new_h = 70;
    }
    else{
        _new_h = 200;
    }

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, _new_h);
    } completion:nil];
```

When increasing the frame's height, the animation works properly.
When decreasing it to the original size, the cell's animation is clunky, quickly reduces the height, without animation, yet the rest of the collectionview animates the change

[image]

Why would this happen only in reducing the height?

Comment: Are the original values related to `new_h == 200` ?

Comment: the above code is in the didSelectItemAtIndexPath, so it checks for a property new_h, if its 200, it sets it to 70, and so forth. From the gif you can see that the block where the address is increasing gradually, but the reverse is sudden and resize to 70 immediatly and not gradually

Comment: Can you post when it is increased the height to could see the differences and try to find a solution @Nick Ginanto?  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your gif, it almost looks like maybe the same problem is happening when you enlarge the cell as well (ie, the background is expanding first, and then the rest of the content follows). Yep, in frame 5, the background color is already gone.

To resize `UICollectionViewCells`, wouldn't you normally set the size in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` rather than manually setting the cell's frame?

I was thinking you would have to call `[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout  invalidateLayout];` and then return the new size in `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`

I'm not sure why the animation would act like it is, but I don't think that's the preferred way to make cell size changes, so that might be affecting it.

Comment: won't invalidating the layout cause the layout the recalculate, and not animate the changes?

Comment: Well I think you will still have to animate the changes. 1) Invalidate the layout. 2) Call `performBatchUpdates:` and make any changes you need to make so that you can return the new size in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` INSIDE this block. 3) Make sure you are returning the new size in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`. I think this should work. It's similar to `UITableView`'s `begin/endUpdates`

Comment: Actually, you might not even need to invalidate the layout, I think it might do that automatically when you call `performBatchUpdates:`. Still, I think you need to change it to return the new size in the delegate method rather than just change the cell's frame manually.

Comment: but that's exactly what I do in the code I wrote in the question. `new_h` is the size in sizeOfItemAtIndexPath

Comment: Is it? I'm not sure what's in your `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`, so I can't know for sure. It just looks like you're manually updating the size of the cell itself. Have you been able to make a smaller, sample project that reproduces the error?

Comment: It may not make a difference, but try updating the value of `_new_h` inside the block, rather than outside.

Comment: Hi i want to execute this,can you help me out with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435196/uicollectionviewcell-animations